# Delete transition link between activities in Navigation Editor tool in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, transition

I am new in Android and I was using the Navigation Editor tool in Android Studio in order to implement the navigation of the app between activities. I was wrong about a link because I set its direction as opposite as I wanted. I was ready to change it but I couldn't. I try to select the link and press the delete key but it doesn't work. I searched in all my app files to find something in the code that represents this link, but I find nothing. I deleted .navigation directory and opened Navigation Editor tool but it doesn't work either. Android documentation (https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/navigation-editor) doesn't help me at all.

So, I want to know how to delete a transition link in the Navigation Editor tool or in some app file in Android Studio.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** SOLVED! When you do a transition in the Navigation Editor Tool in Android Studio, it creates some lines of code setting a listener in the onCreate method of the activity. To delete the transition simply delete these lines. You still can't do it from the Navigation Editor tool. For example:

```
        findViewById(R.id.rl_main).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh man Thanks a lot! I've mess up with my really very big project. Really you helped me a lot!

Comment: I am glad that this helped you! If you could up or fav my question I'll appreciate it. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Ok! Actually I was in hurry so I missed it!

Comment: I have no problem. Thanks you so much! :)